# Why does renaming of files sometimes refactor the classnames and sometimes not?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, file-rename

I found it curious that the file rename sometimes ask to refactor the class inside and (most) sometimes just renames the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a complete list from all answers that I could verify

**The refactoring will not trigger if**

> - the
>     namespace does not exactly match the
>     convention (Foldername =
>     namepsacename)
> - the class
>     is generic
> - the
>     classname didn't match the filename
> - <strike>there are more than one class in the file</strike>
> - <strike>there are errors in the file</strike>
> - <strike>the file is located in another project</strike>

Answer (score 9):

I think the class name has to match the filename exactly. It may also depend on whether your code compiles at the time, though not sure on that point.

Comment: you are right about the filename but, and now I must correct my previous comment, you are not right about the compile errors. It was a related error that stopped the refactor in my testcase. So compile errors didn't affect the refactoring.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what AndrewS said, I belive that if you have multiple classes in a single file, it will also not ask to refactor it.

Comment: I must correct me, the refactoring will work if the class with the filename exist in the file.

Answer (score 3):

There can be problems when the inherited class lays in another assembly. For me a restart of VisualStudio sometimes fixed it.

Comment: I cannot confirm this. Can you post a more exact example?